# VPN Error 800 - Can't connect to network

Tags: windows-7, networking, vpn

Every time I am trying to VPN into the server, it comes up with:

> "Error 800: Unable to establish the VPN connection. The VPN server may be unreachable, or security parameters may not be configured properly for the connection"

The weird thing is, someone in my office, at the same time, can VPN in while I am having issues. Then after so many times of having issues, I eventually can get in. Sometimes I can try connecting all day and sometimes it only takes a couple times for it to eventually work.

My computer is running Windows 7 Pro.

Is there a limit on how many people can VPN in at one time? Is there a setting that I need to change?

Comment: When you say someone in your office *can* connect, are they connecting from within your work network, or are they connecting from home and you contacted them whilst you were at home, too? I ask because the question is vague and may be able to direct the quality of answer.... i.e. both of you are in the office and one can connect, whilst the other cannot, may suggest a client/computer problem; if you are both at home and one can't connect then, from past experience, it may be an ISP router configuration/firewall blocking your VPN (e.g. UK VirginMedia SuperHubs block PPTP VPNs out of the box).

Comment: Lol... very old question... should have read the date...

Answer (score 0):

Hope i can help you regarding your issue. Error 800 is a windows error, It occurs while using the following protocols. PPTP ( Point To Point Tunneling Protocol),L2TP (  Layer 2 Tunneling Protocol).
Which means you unable to connect to the server. Usually this will occur because of the below conflicts.

⇒ Problem in local configuration.

⇒ Incorrect VPN setup.

⇒ Blocking the connection (Your security software,firewall,router)

⇒ This issue may be caused by a router that has the outdated firmware. ( For this kindly check your administrator).

Comment: Would these issues cause it to work sometimes but not others? That's what I am most confused about

Answer (score 0):

VPN Error 800 is one of the most common errors that occur while connecting to VPN. It gives error message that says “Unable to establish the VPN connection. The VPN server may be un-reachable, or security parameters may not be configured properly for this connection.”

Reasons responsible for VPN Error 800 :

- Your router’s firmware is not up to date.
- Firewall may be blocking the connection.
- VPN tunnel type is set to automatic.

How you can fix VPN Error 800:
As you mentioned Password and username is not the issue then you can check other settings such as:

- Router and Firewall settings.
- Try pinging the server to make sure VPN Server is reachable.
- Check PPTP port settings.
- Enable PPTP and VPN Port (TCP 1723) and GRE Port (47) for VPN Connection.

Hope this helps.